# Turning K-Medoids into an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, clustering

I am studying a clustering problem. By reading the literature, I found that the clustering problem can be converted into an optimization problem, K-Medoids can be converted into an integer programming problem. I would like to ask if this kind of integer programming problem can be solved using an exact algorithm.

Comment: Hello. K-Medoids is an algorithm, not a problem. Clustering is a problem, and it's already an optimisation problem. Can you explain in more details what you mean by "turning clustering into an optimisation problem"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found out by reviewing the literature that the K-Medoids clustering algorithm is an optimization problem that finds the shortest distance between points and clusters them. It can be described as an integer programming problem. I am thinking about it when performing cluster analysis. , commonly used clustering algorithms may fall into local optima, affecting the clustering effect. So, can the optimal solution be obtained by solving the clustering optimization problem and form a clustering result with the best quality?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the problem can be solved exactly using common IP algorithms such as branch-and-cut, with the usual qualification that there will be some limit on the size of the problems you can handle. (What that size limit is depends on the hardware and software you are using and how long you are willing to wait for a provably optimal solution.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to ask, can K-Medoids be understood as a discrete P-median problem?

Comment: They are very similar, but I believe K-Medoids is more flexible in terms of what objective function you use.

Answer (score 1):

sure, K-medoids could be expressed as an optimization problem, I recommend you read the paper: Clustering by a means of medoids, Leonard kaufman, peter rousseeuw
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment.